# Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList'

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-bean

I need to add spring security with my custom authentication provider class. This is my security configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me.web.controllers"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myProvider" class="com.me.web.controllers.CustomAuthenticationProvider">

    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config='true'>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:http-basic />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='myProvider'/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

And this is the part from my web.xml related to authentication:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

But I get the following error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.omd.web.controllers.CustomAuthenticationProvider' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.omd.web.controllers.CustomAuthenticationProvider] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Any guess where the issue may be, or where should I look into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> user-service-ref='myProvider'

Your provider is **not**  UserDetailsService, it should be

`<authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider ref="myProvider" />
</authentication-manager>`

Comment: I found it already. There are lots of examples in the internet with that mistake.